# Sort CSV data by multiple columns

Tags: perl, bash, unix

**Input File**

```
1,A,SDF,24,55,55
2,T,AAS,22,12,32
3,TR,SS,14,19,69
4,DD,DD,14,59,39
5,SW,DD,14,39,59
6,SB,DS,12,26,126
7,QQ,SWD,12,19,199
8,QA,DD,12,17,167
9,AA,QQ,10,9,49
```

**Desired Output**

```
1,A,SDF,24,55,55
2,T,AAS,22,12,32
3,TR,SS,14,19,69
5,SW,DD,14,39,59
4,DD,DD,14,59,39
7,QQ,SWD,12,19,199
8,QA,DD,12,17,167
6,SB,DS,12,26,126
9,AA,QQ,10,9,49
```

**Logic** : First sort reverse by 4th column and then sort reverse by 6th column

I tried the following but didnt work

```
sort -t ',' -nrk 4,6 -s Input_file

sort -t ',' -k 4,4n -k 6,6n Input_file
```

Comment: Do you want to sort the 2nd or the 6th column after sorting the 4th?

Comment: Sort 6th column after 4th ..

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/sort-based-on-column-and-characters.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this:

```
kent$  sort -nrt, -k4,4 -k6,6 file                                                                                                                                        
1,A,SDF,24,55,55
2,T,AAS,22,12,32
3,TR,SS,14,19,69
5,SW,DD,14,39,59
4,DD,DD,14,59,39
7,QQ,SWD,12,19,199
8,QA,DD,12,17,167
6,SB,DS,12,26,126
9,AA,QQ,10,9,49
```

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in a Perl solution:

```
print join(',', @$_), "\n" for 
sort { $b->[3] <=> $a->[3] or $b->[5] <=> $a->[5] }
map { chomp; [ split /,/ ] } <>;
```